# Place a whole lot of pads

Tags: pcb-design, altium

We use pads where the pad itself has no diameter (but the accompanying hole does) as break lines in our PCBs. Often those are only 3-4 and can be placed by hand. Now we have a PCB with a break line requiring more of those and closer together (12+ holes).

Doing such by hand is possible but tedious. Can macro's in Altium be used to semi-automate this process?

There's an overlay line present to guide the process and the lines are usually in a 90 degrees angle (so only x or y increments/decrements).

Comment: With hole but without diameter? That's like with snow but without weather.

Comment: Create a PCB footprint that would define the relative position of the break holes.  Then you would place a dozen of these footprints, rather than hundreds of individual holes.

Comment: @OlinLathrop The pad doesn't have a diameter but the hole does. The result is a simple hole without pad.

Comment: The only thing I have done close to this in an automated fashion is have an edge trace and set the via stitching rules such that the holes end up close enough to create the breakline at 1mm holes and -1mm pads and masks, lock them and then remove the trace. Been long ago (many versions) though, so can't say if that's still the fastest trick to it.

Comment: Draw up four or so of them and copy and paste from there. If you end up needing, say, 24, then copy and paste the four, then copy and paste the 8 three times.

Comment: *"The pad doesn't have a diameter but the hole does. The result is a simple hole without pad."* So you have a plain hole that has nothing to do with any pads.  Mentioning "pad" is therefore just pointless and confusing.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I think the confusion is that in Altium holes are created using the "pad" tool. You can create holes using board cutouts but it's usually just easier to place a non-plated through-hole "pad" (the name of the Altium tool) with no annular ring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Altium's Paste Array feature to do this. It would need to be done for each segment.

Start by placing a hole/pad/via at the starting point. Copy this pad, then delete it (it will come back in the next step).

Go to Edit -> Paste Special... (or E, A as a shortcut). The next dialog should have a list of Paste attributes. For this case, you can leave them all unchecked, then hit Paste Array ...

In this dialog, you have a few options. Under item count, select how many copies that you want, including the copy that you deleted. So if you want 10 holes, put 10 under Item Count. Text Increment is for pad numbers. An increment of 1 will make the numbers increase by one each time. If you don't care about this, then put 0. Under Array type, you want Linear. Then under Linear Array, enter the X spacing and/or Y spacing. Negative X values will place the copies to the left, and Negative Y values will place the copies down. If you enter both, the copies will be pasted at an angle.

Finally, click OK and you will be given a crosshair as if you were pasting one part. Click where you want the array to start and the whole array will be pasted.

Altium has more information on these menus:
http://techdoc.altium.com/display/ADRR/PCB_Dlg-PasteSpecial((Paste+Special))_AD
http://techdoc.altium.com/display/ADRR/PCB_Dlg-SetupPasteArray((Setup+Paste+Array))_AD

Answer (score 3):

The easy way to do this is to set your grid spacing to the spacing you want between the holes. Then place your first hole. Now move the grid origin to the center of the first hole, and turn on snap to grid. Now it will be quick and easy to place the remaining holes on each grid intersection to form your hole pattern.

If you are really making a lot of holes (more than 10), as mentioned in the comments, it can speed things up to place 4 or 5 holes, copy them, and then paste additional holes in groups until you've built your complete hole pattern.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a series of holes to physically break the boards apart you might ask your PCB fabricator if he is able to create score line cuts.  These are deep partial cuts in the material that also allow for later board separation.  In most cases using a score line to divide parts can be less of a mess then cracking the material along holes.  The resulting edges from a scored line would also be much more precise. To define a score line you would just need to create lines on a separate layer called Score.